# Bootstrap 3.3.7 modal shown event not working properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I am using Bootstrap 3.3.7

I load a modal on click of a search button and I have links on the modal, when I click on the link I get data based on that,close the modal and polpulate the form.

But the below function does not seem to work properly. I check if the bootstrap is loaded in the console using typeof `$().modal == 'function'` when it returns `true` my function is called and when it returns false the below function is not called. My modal gets loaded since I call it on button itself. I need to refresh a lot and check in console if `$().modal == 'function'` is true to be able to call the function on modal shown.

How do I ensure the bootstrap gets loaded correctly always.

All this code is on a SharePoint aspx page but that should not be an issue I believe

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(event) {

    $('#myTable a.policy-no').on('click', function() {

    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it through the document like this

```
$(document).on('show.bs.modal','#myModal', function () {

    $('#myTable a.policy-no').on('click', function() {

    });

})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use something like this, when ever i use a modal I heck if the modal is already open en stop it from closing. Then I load my new page / data in the already open modal.

```
$(function () {
    $("body").on("click", "button", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // if the modal is already open, you stop it from closing, and open a new form into the modal
    if (($("body").data('bs.modal') || {}).isShown) {
        e.stopPropagation();
    }

    $(".modal-body, .modal-title").html("");

    // Load your page / data
    $(".modal-title").load(URI, function () { });
    $(".modal-body").load(URI, function () { });
    })
});
```